# How to stop c#2.0 race condition occuring when spawning a new thread before the old one is finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-2.0, race-condition

I'm implementing a printer queue to process GDI conversion in c#2.0. The jobs to process are added by a main thread, which sets up a thread per printer to process these jobs. After all the jobs are finished, the printing thread waits for five seconds for any more jobs before expiring.

A new thread is then created, the next time a print job is passed It is important that there be only one thread per printer to keep jobs in sequential order.

Unfortunately there seems to be a race condition when an print job is added right as the thread expires - the Thread.IsAlive can be true just after job has finished processing.

**Can I prevent this from happening?**

A simplified version:

```
private Thread _processor;
readonly private AutoResetEvent _newPrintItemAdded = new AutoResetEvent(true);
readonly ThreadSafeQueueWrapper<IPrintItem> _printingQueue = new ThreadSafeQueueWrapper<IPrintItem>(5);

public void Add(IPrintItem item)
{
    _printingQueue.Enqueue(item);

    //Resume processing thread if waiting.
   _newPrintItemAdded.Set();

   StartProcessorIfNeeded();
 }


public void StartProcessorIfNeeded()
{
    if (_processor != null && _processor.IsAlive) return;

    _processor = new Thread(RunThread)

    _processor.Start();
}

public void RunThread()
{
    //timeout if no items added to queue
    while (_newPrintItemAdded.WaitOne(5000))
    {
        ProcessQueueItems();
    }
      //Thread is alive here, but won't process any more items
}
private void ProcessQueueItems()
{
   // get the print job off the queue
   IPrintItem currentPrinter;
   while (_printingQueue.TryDequeue(out currentPrinter))
   {
      currentPrinter.Print();
   }
}
```

Comment: Create a lock object for each printer?

Comment: 'After all the jobs are finished, the printing thread waits for five seconds for any more jobs before expiring' - why bother with this?  You have dozens of printers or what?  Just leave the thread running and dodge this issue entirely.

Comment: No, there would be only 2-3 printers, so 2-3 threads. Code is part of a very large client application though so I'm leery of leaving threads running for the application lifetime that won't be needed. Unless I've misunderstood something of course.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something.  2-3 app-lifetime threads is fine.

Comment: It's like this.  In order of simplicity, efectiveness, ease of management and reliablilty: 1) Pooled tasks, 2) App-lifetime threads, -9999) Continually creating/terminating/destroying threads.

Answer (score 2):

Just wait for the old thread to exit. Don't use pooling solutions like `IsAlive` because they rarely work.

```
if (_processor != null) _processor.Join();
```

Comment: Method Add(IPrintItem item) is called by the gui thread though - won't this cause the application to freeze until it the printing thread is done?

Comment: True. You need to place the wait at a point where it doesn't hurt. For example inside of the thread proc of the new thread. The new thread itself should wait for the old to exit. If you're using tasks all of this becomes much easier.

Comment: ndeed - however we still need to support 2.0 for the client, servers can be latest though, thank goodness. So are you suggesting two threads, the currently running one, and the one which will take over?

Comment: Yes. You have to arrange for the old `Thread` to be available to the new thread proc. You could make `RunThread` receive it as a parameter. You'd need to change `new Thread(RunThread)` to using a lambda to call `RunThread` with the old thread (which you need to copy to a local first due to clusre capture semantics). I hope that helps. If I got something wrong here you surely can fix it up.

Comment: Add gets called for every printer job though, so wouldn't this result in either printing threads B-D all waiting on thread A to finish, or D waiting for C, waiting for B, waiting for A?

Comment: @jamesdwalker yeah you'd have to arrange for the correct threads waiting for other correct threads. I'm out at this point. I think you got the idea of how this can be done. My main point is that waiting, not polling, is the correct approach.